# how to do multiple auto concatenation across all strings in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here example of mydata

```
mydata=structure(list(V1 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_B_3E3B"
), V2 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_B_3OLS3B"), V3 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", 
"dt_spring_B_4B4E"), V4 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_B_4OS4E"
), V5 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_B_4S4OS"), V6 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", 
"dt_spring_B_OLS"), V7 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_b_os"
), V8 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_E_3E3B"), V9 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", 
"dt_spring_E_3E3C"), V10 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_E_3C3OC"
), V11 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_E_4E4B"), V12 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", 
"dt_spring_E_4S4B"), V13 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_E_5E5B"
), V14 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", "dt_spring_E_5S5B"), V15 = c("dt_spring_B_3B3OS", 
"dt_spring_E_C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))
```

i need to concatenate the string values in such way, where the  value of cell above should always have "equals" sign in front of them.
To be more clearly what i need . Consider the example.
The first column `V1`

```
V1
dt_spring_B_3B3OS
dt_spring_B_3E3B
```

above cell has value `dt_spring_B_3B3OS`, after it value must be sign equal(=).
Therefore, after concatenation, we should have something like this  template.

```
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_3E3B).
```

if we say simple,then the concatenation pattern is the `values of the upper cell + vs +  value of the lower cell and = .`
In excel it is very easy to do this. `=CONCATENATE(A2;"vs";A3;"=";"(";A2;",";A3;")")`
But the question is how to do such  concatenation for all columns in the dataset at once?
On this reproducible example, the desired result should be something like this.(got via excel, but i need it via R.)

```
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_3E3B)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3OLS3B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_3OLS3B)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4B4E=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_4B4E)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4OS4E=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_4OS4E)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4S4OS=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_4S4OS)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_OLS=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_OLS)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_b_os=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_b_os)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_3E3B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_3E3B)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_3E3C=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_3E3C)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_3C3OC=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_3C3OC)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_4E4B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_4E4B)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_4S4B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_4S4B)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_5E5B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_5E5B)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_5S5B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_5S5B)
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_C=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_C)
```

Any help is always important to me. Thank you

Comment: `unname(sapply(mydata, function(x) sprintf("%svs%s=(%s,%s)", x[1], x[2], x[1], x[2])))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
mydata %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~paste0(first(.), 'vs', last(.), '=(', first(.), ',', last(.), ')')))
```

which gives:

```
    V1
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_3E3B)
                                                                            V2
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3OLS3B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_3OLS3B)
                                                                        V3
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4B4E=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_4B4E)
                                                                          V4
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4OS4E=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_4OS4E)
                                                                          V5
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4S4OS=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_4S4OS)
                                                                      V6
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_OLS=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_B_OLS)
                                                                    V7
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_b_os=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_b_os)
                                                                        V8
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_3E3B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_3E3B)
                                                                        V9
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_3E3C=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_3E3C)
                                                                         V10
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_3C3OC=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_3C3OC)
                                                                       V11
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_4E4B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_4E4B)
                                                                       V12
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_4S4B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_4S4B)
                                                                       V13
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_5E5B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_5E5B)
                                                                       V14
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_5S5B=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_5S5B)
                                                                 V15
1 dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_E_C=(dt_spring_B_3B3OS,dt_spring_E_C)
```

If you just want to have one character vector, add an `unlist` pipe at the end of the code.